# Partial Differential Equations: Fourier Transform in Space and Time?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Consider the one-dimensional wave equation:
$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi(x, t) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x, t).$$
We can take the Fourier transform of $\psi(x,t)$ with respect to $x$:
$$\mathcal{F}\{\psi(x, t)\}(k) = \hat{\psi}(k, t).$$
Therefore, the wave equation becomes:
$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\hat{\psi}(k, t) = - k^2 \hat{\psi}(k, t).$$
Although the resulting equation doesn't make much sense, can we repeat this process and take the Fourier transform of $\hat{\psi}(k, t)$ with respect to $t$ to have
$$\frac{l^2}{c^2}\hat{\hat{\psi}}(k, l) = k^2 \hat{\hat{\psi}}(k, l)?$$
In general, can we use the Fourier transform to eliminate all derivatives from any PDE?

Comment: Not generally, for instance parabolic equations can't generally be solved backward in time so the Fourier transform on the time domain $\mathbb R$ won't be defined.

Comment: In equations where one of the coordinates is time, a Laplace transform is often used for that coordinate instead of the Fourier transform because time only travels in one direction.

Answer (score 4):

I think your impression here is generally correct, but let's be specific: *if* we *assume* that the function $\psi(x,t)$ is a tempered distribution as a "function" of two variables, then, yes, we can take Fourier transforms, and a constant-coefficient PDE becomes an equation involving no derivatives.

For (linear) wave equations, the hypothesis that $\psi$ is tempered is not unreasonable.

For *heat* equations, there is a problem, both in physical terms and in mathematical terms. Physically, lots of scenarios cannot be run backward beyond some time $t_o$. Mathematically, in parallel, there are lots of (physically interesting/meaningful) set-ups where, as a function of $t$, $\psi(x,t)$ cannot be reasonably extended backward. In those cases, as in comments, one-sided things that accommodate boundare/initial conditions (Laplace...) are more relevant.