# Partial differential equations: Mellin transform in space and time?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, parabolic-pde, mellin-transform

This is related to: [Partial Differential Equations: Fourier Transform in Space and Time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648332/460999), and [The equation $r^2 \frac{\partial ^3\Psi(r,s)}{\partial r^3}=s^2 \frac{\partial \Psi(r,s)}{\partial s}.$ Possible connections in physics and math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4736695/460999)

Consider the function, or distribution:

$$\Psi(r,x)=\exp {\frac{r}{\log x}}$$

which satisfies the linear second order parabolic partial differential equation:

$$r \frac{\partial ^2\Psi(r,x)}{\partial r^2}=-x \frac{\partial \Psi(r,x)}{\partial x} \tag{1}$$

Let $\hat \Psi$ be the [Mellin transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html)* of $\Psi$ w.r.t. $x.$ Then $\hat \Psi $ satisfies the below linear third order partial differential equation:

$$\hat \Psi(r,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{r s})$$

$$r^2 \frac{\partial ^3\hat \Psi(r,s)}{\partial r^3}=s^2 \frac{\partial \hat \Psi(r,s)}{\partial s} \tag{2}$$

where $K_1$ is the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

This implies that the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are connected through the Mellin transform.

I'm aware that the *Laplace* transform is more often used in cases where the PDE is parabolic. Furthermore, I'm struggling with the physical interpretation of $(r,s)$-space. Would this be $r$ (space) and $s$ (complex time) or something? But it's hard to get a read on the physical interpretation of the Mellin transform. I do know that the Mellin transform is *scale invariant*...another thought I had was to view $(1)$ in terms of a *heat* equation with $r$ (space) and $x$ (time).

> Is there an interpretation here, even if it doesn't make sense physically? Am I on the right track with my own interpretation (i.e. thinking of $(1)$ as a *heat* equation etc.)?

*More details on $\hat \Psi$ and $\Psi$ being connected by the Mellin transform:

$$\int_0^1 x^{s-1} \exp \frac{r}{\log x}~dx =\hat \Psi(r,s)$$

Comment: Perhaps the [relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Relationship_to_other_transforms) between the Mellin and Fourier transforms provides some insight.

Comment: @StevenClark Potentially, yes